# How to calculate the posterior probabilty of Gaussian Mixture Component

Tags: bayesian, posterior, gaussian-mixture-distribution, generalized-moments, probabilistic-programming

If the mean vector and the Covariance matrix of a Gaussian Mixture model are known, how could I calculate the posterior probability of each of the Gaussian Component in the mixture.